# Can a linear matrix inequality constraint transform to second-order cone constraint(s)?

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-matrix-inequality

Maybe the answer for the general case is NO but consider the following problem as maximizing the minimum singular value of a matrix:

$minimize\,\,\,\,{\sigma _{\min }}$

$subject\,\,to\,\,{A^T}A - {\sigma _{\min }}I \succeq 0$

The constraint ${A^T}A - {\sigma _{\min }}I \succeq 0$ is a Linear Matrix Inequality (LMI) constraint since one can write ${\sigma _{\min }}I \preceq {A^T}A$ (${A^T}A,\,and\,{\sigma _{\min }}I \in {S^n}\left( {symmetric\,matrices} \right)$).

Is there any way to represent the above constraint as second-order cone constraint(s)?

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Comment: Could you tell me why or give me a clue to prove that?

Comment: You can't prove a negative. But consider this: it is possible to represent a second-order cone constraint as an LMI. So that means that LMIs are _at least_ as complex as second-order cone constraints. It stands to reason they might be _more_ complex.

Comment: I understand the a second-order cone constraint can be transformed to LMI but reverse is not possible in general case so I do not want to prove the general case.

Comment: I do not want to prove the general case for the reverse (LMI to SOCC). To elaborate my problem, I have a question for you. Does what your said means that the feasible set of the above constraint which lies in the semidefinite cone (the cone that includes the feasible set of the above constraint) does not have any intersection with any second order cone?

Comment: To add to this discussion: this paper https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-018-1233-0 shows that in general the $3 \times 3$ SDP cone has no finite sized SOCP representation (and the same result holds for any $k >3$).